# Extracting from HTML with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I try to extract lotto numbers from https://www.lotto.de/de/ergebnisse/lotto-6aus49/archiv.html (I know there is an easier way, but it's rather for learning).

[image: These are the numbers I want to extract:]

Tried with Python, beautifulsoup the following:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="https://www.lotto.de/de/ergebnisse/lotto-6aus49/archiv.html"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
numbers=soup.findAll('li',{'class':'winning_numbers.boxRow.clearfix'})

for number in numbers:
    print number['li']+","+number.string
```

Returns nothing, which I actually expected. I read the tutorial, but still didn't understand the parsing totally. Could someone give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: same result, returns nothing :(

Comment: actually error is in `numbers=soup.findAll('li',{'class':'winning_numbers.boxRow.clearfix'})`

Comment: i guessed so, but which is the error and how should it be?

Comment: I checked HTML of page their are no number within those `li` tags!

Comment: do you click on some button to reach this page? or directly hits this url, because there is no li tag with number string

Comment: i directly request that page but it seems to be dynamically generated, that's why the contents seen in the browser can't been found when accessing the page via beautifulsoup

Comment: Yes, I also hit url directly and inspected HTML using "developer tool" (as 'inspect Element') and via "view source" button I think something done by JavaScript/Ajax etc that dynamically fill HTML (on page load etc.). That is why I deleted my answer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the data content is dynamically generated, one of the *EASIER* solutions you may use **[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org)** or alike to simulate the action as a browser (I use **[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org)** as webdriver), like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://www.lotto.de/de/ergebnisse/lotto-6aus49/archiv.html"
# I'm using PhantomJS, you may use your own...
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
# I just simply go through the div class and grab all number texts
# without special number, like in the Sample
for ul in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'winning_numbers'}):
    n = ','.join(li for li in ul.text.split() if li.isdigit())
    if n:
        print 'number: {}'.format(n)

number: 6,25,26,27,28,47
```

To also grab the special number:

```
for ul in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'winning_numbers'}):
    # grab only numeric chars, you may apply your own logic here
    n = ','.join(''.join(_ for _ in li if _.isdigit()) for li in ul.text.split())
    if n:
        print 'number: {}'.format(n)

number: 6,25,26,27,28,47,5 # with special number
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, interesting solution, but for `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')` I am getting `Screenshot: available via screen` exception how to resolve it?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, which means the `executable_path` is not configured properly, try go to your terminal and type `which phantomjs` and replace what's in the code and it should work :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, which I meant above is that you need to replace the path to your **phantomjs** executable path, in *nix we can find out the path in terminal by `which phantomjs`, if its in Windows, you need to find out where your executable exe file is and point to there.

Comment: I have  the executable_path configured properly, under windows phatomjs asked to pass the firewall. Then it takes some seconds but still it returns nothing...hmm

Comment: @royskatt, I'm not very familiar to Windows, but if you've installed **PhantomJS** properly and this doesn't work as expected, you may try using **webdriver.Firefox()** or **Chrome** and try again?

Comment: @Anzel: I checked the content of the variable soup. It actually contains the dynamically generated numbers. That means something in the for-loop doesn't work or works differently under windows. But I can also catch the number with a Regex from the soup-variable.
Thank you very much for your example!

Comment: @royskatt, yes the **for/loop** and **join** isn't ideal I was just trying to show it should work in this approach, and glad it helps :)

Comment: @royskatt, as a side note, a more appropriate solution is to `assert` the text in li is not empty... good luck

Comment: I'm still unhappy that the parsing doens't work and I have to regex it the dirty way.

Comment: @royskatt, look at the `driver.page_source` and see the attributes of the dynamic element. BeautifulSoup should be more than enough to get the text in `<li>` elements.

Comment: @Anzel: just one more question, what is that underscore doing, that you are using to grab the special number? Never saw thar before.

Comment: @royskatt, oh... underscore in python normally is used as temp variable that we do not care, or in interpreter as the "previous result"

Comment: @Anzel: Ah i see, so a little like the $_ variable in good old Perl :-)